# Extjs panel. Keyboard events

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, keyboard-shortcuts, extjs3

I have a panel which I am rendering using following code.

```
new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'textPanel',
    height: 1000,
    width: 1200,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    html:"An HTML fragment, or a DomHelper specification to use as the layout element content. The HTML content is added after the component is rendered, so the document will not contain this HTML at the time the render event is fired. This content is inserted into the body before any configured contentEl is appended."
});
```

And then I want to listen to event when an enter key is pressed. So, I am creating a KeyMap as follows...

```
var map = new Ext.KeyMap(Ext.getCmp('textPanel').body, {
    key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
    fn: onKeyPress,
    //  handler: onKeyPress,
    scope: this
});
```

But the onKeyPress function is not being called.

I have already tried using

```
Ext.getCmp('textPanel').body.dom,
Ext.getCmp('textPanel').el.dom,
Ext.getCmp('textPanel').el
```

instead of

```
Ext.getCmp('textPanel').body
```

with no success.

If I use "document" there then the onKeyPress function is called. i.e.

```
var map = new Ext.KeyMap(document, {
    key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
    fn: onKeyPress,
    //  handler: onKeyPress,
    scope: this
});
```

This works perfectly but I don't want to listen to whole document.
How can I listen to just the panel?

Comment: What do you mean "listen to the panel"?  Is your panel supposed to be a `TextField`?  It doesn't make sense to listen to a key event on just an ordinary `Ext.Panel`...

Comment: My panel has text in its body. And I want to do something when an enter or tab key is pressed within the body of a panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In extjs 3.4, if you want to use `KeyMap` then you need to first set focus on the panel element, otherwise key events will always fire at document level hence you will not able to listen for key events on panel (that's why you were able to listen key events on document only)

But in extjs there isn't any way to set focus on panel, so therefore you will need to create a custom panel class which can set focus to itself and listen key events

```
Ext.namespace('Saket');

Saket.FocusPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    onRender : function()
    {
        Saket.FocusPanel.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);

        // this element allows the Window to be focused for keyboard events
        this.focusEl = this.el.createChild({
                    tag: 'a', href:'#', cls:'x-dlg-focus',
                    tabIndex:'-1', html: '&#160;'});
        this.focusEl.swallowEvent('click', true);

        this.getEl().on({
            click : this.focus,
            scope : this
        });
    },
    focus : function()
    {
        this.focusEl.focus();
    }    
});

new Saket.FocusPanel({
    id: 'textPanel',
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    html:"An HTML fragment, or a DomHelper specification to use as the layout element content. The HTML content is added after the component is rendered, so the document will not contain this HTML at the time the render event is fired. This content is inserted into the body before any configured contentEl is appended.",
    keys: {
        key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
        fn: function() {alert('bingo');},
        scope: this
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/silentsakky/PdyqW/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains conceptually why I was not able to capture event on panel.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listeners for `keydown` on the panel's element using `getEl()`:

```
Ext.getCmp('textPanel').getEl().on('keydown', function(f, e) {
    if (e.getKey() === Ext.EventObject.ENTER)
    {
        //do whatever you want here
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?  This is working for me with 4.1.3 and 4.2.1.