# How to temporary expand collapsed panel on mouse over title bar in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a border layout with two panels inside center and west regions. By default, west panel is collapsed and if you click on any part of the title bar while is collapsed, the panel is temporary expanded until you move the mouse pointer out of its boundaries.

What I want to do is to have this same "temporary expand" not by clicking on the panel's title bar, but just hovering over it. How can I make that possible?

Here is my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width: 500,
        height: 300,

        layout: 'border',

        items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Center Panel',
                region: 'center',
                flex: 1
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'West Panel',
                region: 'west',
                flex: 1,

                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                animCollapse: false,
                collapseDirection: Ext.Component.DIRECTION_BOTTOM,
                titleCollapse: true
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

Please refer to the following fiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/3FJ58/3/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but you have to extend from `Ext.panel.Panel` to override the `getPlaceholder` method that is used by the borderlayout

```
getPlaceholder: function(direction) {
    var me = this,
        collapseDir = direction || me.collapseDirection,
        listeners = null,
        placeholder = me.placeholder,
        floatable = me.floatable,
        titleCollapse = me.titleCollapse;

    if (!placeholder) {
        if (floatable || (me.collapsible && titleCollapse)) {
            listeners = {
                mouseenter: {
                    // titleCollapse needs to take precedence over floatable
                    fn: (!titleCollapse && floatable) ? me.floatCollapsedPanel : me.toggleCollapse,
                    element: 'el',
                    scope: me
                }
            };
        }

        me.placeholder = placeholder = Ext.widget(me.createReExpander(collapseDir, {
            id: me.id + '-placeholder',
            listeners: listeners
        }));
    }

    // User created placeholder was passed in
    if (!placeholder.placeholderFor) {
        // Handle the case of a placeholder config
        if (!placeholder.isComponent) {
            me.placeholder = placeholder = me.lookupComponent(placeholder);
        }
        Ext.applyIf(placeholder, {
            margins: me.margins,
            placeholderFor: me
        });

        placeholder.addCls([Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'region-collapsed-placeholder', Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'region-collapsed-' + collapseDir + '-placeholder', me.collapsedCls]);
    }

    return placeholder;
}
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FJ58/9/)

Overriding is at least the cleanest way IMO. But it would also be possible to manipulate the placeholder created by the borderlayout.

@JoseRivas already posted something like this but with some issues I will add the snipped how this can be done in a cleaner way

```
listeners: {
   afterrender: function(p){
      p.placeholder.getEl().on('mouseenter', function(){ p.floatCollapsedPanel() })
   }
}
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FJ58/10/)

Comment: I agree that overriding is the cleanest way of doing it, although I liked the small alternative, and since I'm building a prototype I'm going to use that alternative for now :) Thanks @sra and @JoseRivas!

Answer (score 0):

jacoviza. Can you try to capture focus event of panel. this link helps you. [Extjs panel. Keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405710/extjs-panel-keyboard-events)

Comment: focus event is never triggered on mouse over :(

Answer (score -1):

add a listener to the el of the placeholder for mouseover and then call the floatCollapsedPanel()

```
  Ext.onReady(function () {
  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,

    layout: 'border',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'panel1',
        region: 'center',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'panel2',
        region: 'west',
        flex: 1,
        id: 'mypanel2',
        collapsible: true,
        collapsed: true,
        animCollapse: false,
        collapseDirection: Ext.Component.DIRECTION_BOTTOM,
        titleCollapse: true,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: {
                fn: function (self) {
                    self.placeholder.getEl().on('mouseover', function () {
                        var panel = Ext.getCmp('mypanel2');
                        panel.floatCollapsedPanel()

                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

});

Comment: it is bad to assign id by yourself. Anyway you already got the panel, so why fetch it again? And please note that the downvote was not done by me.

Comment: Ok, this is a stupid reason... There is A. No reason for using it B. No hint for the reader that this is bad practice. Now you got my -1